# How to watch a traffic for a specific app?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, proxy, wireshark, mitmproxy

I would like to see what is going on when the app (win32 executable) is waiting for a response from the server.

For the web application, when you want to check the network activity, you go to **Chrome Dev Tool** and check the **Network tab** to see the traffic like in the image below:

[image]

How would I do the same for the some Windows application ? I tried to trace the communication with Wireshark, but it shows some unknown "hebrew" stuff.

[image]

I also tried to use **Man in the middle** approach with [MITMPROXY](https://mitmproxy.org/), by setting the OS to specific PROXY: `localhost:8080`, but it works only for web browser and not the app itself.

Is there something you could suggest to do or to try some other methods ?

Comment: Have you tried Nirsoft (nirsoft.net) TCP View ?  That is by App.

Comment: The Wireshark trace shows that the communication uses TLS. Therefore you need the master secret for decrypting traffic (which can be difficult to get). Personally I would recommend [Fiddler Classic](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddler-classic) (free, closed-source), which is also a Windows program and can identify the program which causes the traffic. If also supports TLS interception and decryption which can work as long as the app does not do certificate pinning.

Comment: I tried Fiddler, but it does not show anything except the Web Browser traffic. Am I doing wrong something ? I just can't spin it up to listen for traffic on specific app.

Comment: If the program you want to see the traffic of a regular program or an UWP app? First start Fiddler and then the program you want to see the data. When Fiddler was active and acted as system proxy you should see at least the CONNECT requests, otherwise the program ignores the Windows proxy settings. If that is the case it is getting complicated.